# Parse Json with Jackson Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, object, jackson

I´m developing an app that uses a lot of json, I was using Gson to parse, but it was really slow and now I´m trying to use Jackson, it´s the first time that I heard of it, so I don´t know how to use it very well. 
My json it´s like:

```
{
    "action": "login",
    "status": true,
    "message": "OK",
    "duration": 144,
    "response": {
        "token": "b6a1e3b87c86531d91afa91bb23aca46"
    }
}
```

And my class to deserialize it´s like:

```
public class HttpWebServiceObject {
    private String action;
    private boolean status;
    private String message;
    private String duration;
    private String response;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Someone could help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED:

I can have a json like this too:

```
{
    "action": "getUserFollowers",
    "status": true,
    "message": "OK",
    "duration": 187,
    "response": [
        {
            "id": "20810",
            "name": "thyago",
            "username": "thyago",
            "location": "guarujá,brasil",
            "photo": "profile/48d15179063126b40f6a5b1bbdea7f1e.jpg",
            "following": false,
            "numfollowing": 3,
            "numfollowers": 7
        },
        {
            "id": "933",
            "name": "Edson Alves",
            "username": "prazermatheus",
            "location": "Rio de Janeiro, Brasil.",
            "photo": "profile/bcc90c29054781adcd4569bb59251dba.jpg",
            "following": false,
            "numfollowing": 2689,
            "numfollowers": 1373
        },
        {
            "id": "753",
            "name": "Yasmim Teófilo",
            "username": "yasmim_gomesz",
            "location": "Pacajus, Brasil",
            "photo": "/profile/default.png",
            "following": false,
            "numfollowing": 1,
            "numfollowers": 6
        },
        {
            "id": "531",
            "name": "Muriel Aragão",
            "username": "muriaragao",
            "location": "Salvador, Brasil",
            "photo": "profile/0f6b504736723ea80c9cd15dabb3f0c5.jpg",
            "following": false,
            "numfollowing": 348,
            "numfollowers": 32
        },
        {
            "id": "492",
            "name": "shashank",
            "username": "shashank",
            "location": "india",
            "photo": "/profile/default.png",
            "following": false,
            "numfollowing": 5,
            "numfollowers": 3
        },
        {
            "id": "307",
            "name": "Clineu Iansen",
            "username": "clineu",
            "location": "Curitiba, Brazil",
            "photo": "profile/3d37a1e9c795a83c672ecacf575ee30a.jpg",
            "following": false,
            "numfollowing": 57,
            "numfollowers": 946
        },
        {
            "id": "277",
            "name": "maharshi",
            "username": "india",
            "location": "india",
            "photo": "profile/86d403617a30469f11403f0c9c65141b.jpg",
            "following": true,
            "numfollowing": 16,
            "numfollowers": 1848
        },
        {
            "id": "57",
            "name": "Alexandre",
            "username": "xandyhsf",
            "location": "Itajai, Brasil",
            "photo": "/profile/default.png",
            "following": false,
            "numfollowing": 51,
            "numfollowers": 16
        },
        {
            "id": "34",
            "name": "Karina Ceconello Ton",
            "username": "KarinaCeconello",
            "location": "Quatro Barras/Brasil",
            "photo": "profile/9bc1fb97263dc9a242766c87e4acf1c4.jpg",
            "following": false,
            "numfollowing": 5,
            "numfollowers": 198
        },
        {
            "id": "25",
            "name": "Thiago Bodruk",
            "username": "ThiagoBodruk",
            "location": "Quatro Barras, Brazil",
            "photo": "profile/56111881a4ebe0f0fc5cb85faa262e17.jpg",
            "following": false,
            "numfollowing": 26,
            "numfollowers": 221
        }
    ]
}
```

How I could do a general parse to deseriliaze this and just take response as a string?

Comment: given the size of your json, gson should not be slow.

Comment: In this request, gson it´s not slow, but in other yes.

Answer (score 0):

first change your pojo like this

```
public class HttpWebServiceObject {
  private String action;
  private boolean status;
  private String message;
  private String duration;
  private Response response; // as your json string it is a object. not a String. so create a seperate  pojo for response

  //getters and setters
```

}

then you can use `ObjectMapper` to convert to java objects from json string.
for example

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HttpWebServiceObject httpWebServiceObject = mapper.readValue(yourJsonString,HttpWebServiceObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what your `HttpWebServiceObject.java` and `Response.java` should look like. This was generated using [this website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) which takes json and converts it to pojos. Once you have these two classes you can then use an `ObjectMapper` to map the json string to these classes.

-----------------------------------com.example.HttpWebServiceObject.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"action",
"status",
"message",
"duration",
"response"
})
public class HttpWebServiceObject {

@JsonProperty("action")
private String action;
@JsonProperty("status")
private Boolean status;
@JsonProperty("message")
private String message;
@JsonProperty("duration")
private Integer duration;
@JsonProperty("response")
private Response response;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The action
*/
@JsonProperty("action")
public String getAction() {
return action;
}

/**
* 
* @param action
* The action
*/
@JsonProperty("action")
public void setAction(String action) {
this.action = action;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The status
*/
@JsonProperty("status")
public Boolean getStatus() {
return status;
}

/**
* 
* @param status
* The status
*/
@JsonProperty("status")
public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
this.status = status;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The message
*/
@JsonProperty("message")
public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

/**
* 
* @param message
* The message
*/
@JsonProperty("message")
public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The duration
*/
@JsonProperty("duration")
public Integer getDuration() {
return duration;
}

/**
* 
* @param duration
* The duration
*/
@JsonProperty("duration")
public void setDuration(Integer duration) {
this.duration = duration;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The response
*/
@JsonProperty("response")
public Response getResponse() {
return response;
}

/**
* 
* @param response
* The response
*/
@JsonProperty("response")
public void setResponse(Response response) {
this.response = response;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

-----------------------------------com.example.Response.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"token"
})
public class Response {

@JsonProperty("token")
private String token;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The token
*/
@JsonProperty("token")
public String getToken() {
return token;
}

/**
* 
* @param token
* The token
*/
@JsonProperty("token")
public void setToken(String token) {
this.token = token;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```